# 5w resistor circuit and increasing circuit speakers power

Tags: prototyping

I am new to electronics, and I am working on an amplifier circuit that contain LM386. 
This is the schema of it with bill of materials:

[image]

[image]

Does this circuit give a huge sound ? If not, do I need to increase speakers "W" or I need to make changes with circuits and resistors ?
And by the way, can I replace a 5W resistor with a normal 1K resistor ?

Comment: Where's the 5 W (watt) resistor. Do you mean the 5k, P1?

Comment: It's poor form to completely replace the original question with a new one. Rather ask another question if you have a new question.

Comment: sir, when I was editing my question, I wanted to add some pictures, and I mistakenly i removed the question about potentiometer. Now I am unable to re-edit because of reports to the admin I guess

Comment: Huge sound will be interpreted differently by different people. Most likely you will have to change the speaker wattage and for that you might have to change the driver circuit as well.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack if i changed only the wattage, will my circuit still working even with the same driver ?

Comment: What is the purpose of the amplifier? Then we can estimate the power you need. Then we can recommend an amplifier. To give you a feel for power requirements: 0.5 W -> headphones / toy radio. 2 - 10 W -> decent radio. 10 W - 50 W -> decent hi-fi. 100 - 400 W -> small PA system. 1000 - 10 kW -> idiotic indoors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The item in the photo is a preset potentiometer. 'Preset' means it's adjusted during setup and left alone unlike a regular potentiometer used for a volume control, for example.

If you inspect it you might be able to see a circular resistance track going from the bottom left pin the long way around the edge to the other pin. There will also be a wiper connected to a third pin. Adjusting the knob will rotate the wiper allowing adjustment of the voltage or potential (hence potentiometer) anywhere between the values on the two end of track pins.

To answer your second question: no. 5 W means 5 watts and is a measure of the power the resistor can dissipate without going up in smoke. 1k is short for 1 kΩ (kilo ohm) - 1000 Ω and is a measure of resistance. You generally need to get the resistance value right for the circuit to work as intended. You need to use a resistor with a power (wattage) rating at least as high as the power it will need to dissipate.

[Edit after OP added schematic and question on power.]

No. 0.5 W is very low power. This amplifier would be used in a small portable transistor radio.

Comment: se my edits please

Answer (score 1):

The image you posted is a potentiometer. It has 3 legs - I'll call them left middle and right. Resistance bwtween Left and Right leg is constant and equal to the value of the pot (say 1kOhm or 10kOhm). Resistance between Left and Middle (as well as Right and Middle) will change as you rotate the knob. Again, R(Left to Middle) + R(Middle to Right) = R(pot) = Constant. This will show you how it works:

[image: Potentiometer]

Usually, it's used to make an adjustable voltage divider. You add GND to Left and VCC to Right. You can get any voltage between VCC and GND on the Middle leg depending upon the knob position.

[image: Pot work]

> Replacing 5W resistor with 1K

Both are two different things. Usually a resistor is specified as Value + Wattage + Tolerance. For ex - 5 Ohms 1 watt 5% resistor. In most cases we ignore the tolerance and use value + wattage. If it's a 5W resistor, it must be getting pretty hot while usage. First of all figure out the resistance of that 5 watt resistor. You can only use that value. Also, common resistors are 0.25 watt. So they will get hot and burn out.

You can use this trick if you don't have exact value: If your 5 W resistor has a value of 1 ohm and you have 0.25 watt resistors of value 20 ohms, you can put 20 resistors of value 20 ohm together in parallel. This will give you a resistor of 1 ohm and 5 watts.

Comment: see my edits please

Answer (score 0):

The component in the photo is a variable resistor, adjustable width a screwdriver. It's also called a trimpot.

If your design calls for a 5 W resistor, you should probably use a 5 W one. The value is independent of the power rating, so it might be a 5 W 1 kOhm resistor. But if you mean a 1/4 W resistor, no, that probably won't work.

Comment: see my edits please